# Do ThreadPoolExecutors that create daemon threads require shutdown?

Tags: java, threadpool, daemon, shutdown

This seemed to happen in my application but was almost certainly the result of something else going on in my Maven / JUnit test case environment (on code I haven't even fully read - maintaining a foreign project).  The following code works as desired, and the TPE doesn't require shutdown:

```
final ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor pool = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1, new ThreadFactory() {

        @Override
        public Thread newThread(Runnable task) {

            Thread thread = new Thread(task, replenisherThreadName);
            thread.setDaemon(true);
            return thread;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it is truly a daemon thread, then it is not keeping your application alive.  your problem lies elsewhere (or it's not *really* a daemon thread).

Comment: This happened during a maven JUnit test that terminated when I manually shutdown the pool but hung indefinitely when the pool was left to its daemon status.  I'll try to isolate that more narrowly if there's a chance that could cause the problem in the surefire framework.

Comment: @djechlin - are you sure that all the pool threads were daemon?  how are you making the threads daemon?

Comment: @djechlin - did you get a stack dump of the hung process?

Comment: Not yet, and now it's "not doing it anymore" which means I jumped the gun when asking this question instead of making sure it was clear and reproducible.  I'll delete shortly...

Comment: Actually, no, not deleting.  I had trouble finding documentation that clearly stated that TPE's that produce daemon threads won't delete which is why I posted here instead of going through the debugging steps you're suggesting, so it's still a useful question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about these daemon threads getting created via your program but ideally we should try to shutdown executor service, after completing our work. The reason being, I have observed it in many applications that when these services are not shutdown properly; thread count keep on piling up and this makes application unstable.